# Google Chrome window become few times wider than screen width

Tags: google-chrome, screen

Google Chrome window become few times wider than screen width

So now it almost impossible to see all my tabs and part of pages contents because it now out of screen (

Screen width is 1366

When I open Chrome, it show one empty startup tab, then I proceed with restore tabs from previous session and it open second window (with all my previously opened tabs) that is very wide. I have use this approach early many times, but such behavior appears for the first time.

Document width (obtained in developers console among browsers tab) is 3731

I can change Chrome height but I can't change width less 3731 px.

Ubuntu 20.04

Chrome 84.0.4147.89